# Put values from DB into array

Tags: php, arrays, database, if-statement

I want to put my DB values into array

```
 $lic=array();
if ($lic[0] == 1)
{
    echo "Pirma lic ir";
}
elseif ($lic[0] == 0)
{
    echo "Pirma lic nav";
}
else
{

}


if ($lic[1] == 1)
{
    echo "Otra lic ir";
}
elseif ($lic[1] == 0)
{
    echo "Otra lic nav";
}
else
{

}
```

$lic I get from my DB

```
$lic = mysql_real_escape_string($row['lic']); // licences
```

So from

```
echo " ".$lic." "; <<<<<----- from this
```

From this I get 1,1,1,1,1 - all of them can be 0 or 1.

I want to put them into array so I can define what's first,second,third
I want them to be in array() <- Inside this
How do I get it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so u mean you want to split the string from
"1, 1, 1, 0 ,1" to array??

so to split you can use ..

```
// if you $lic is like below 
$lic  = "1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0";

$arr = explode(", ", $lic);

echo $arr[0]; // 1
echo $arr[1]; // 1
echo $arr[2]; // 0
```